# How to tell Safari NOT to uncompress a compressed attachment

Tags: safari, http-headers

My application needs to allow a user to download a gzipped tar file. This bit is working.

Safari, by default, automatically uncompresses the file in the download directory, making it a `tar` file rather than a `tar.gz` file.

I want to tell Safari not to do this - but I want the message that I send back to tell Safari not to uncompress the file. I don't want the user to have to alter their browser settings in order to achieve this.

Is it possible?

The current request headers look like

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:134
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=D577A975B31ABFEFDCD69359CF50A82A
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/app1/download
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36`

The response looks like

`Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=dave.tar.gz
Date:Fri, 28 Aug 2015 08:05:56 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked`

The file ( on safari ) that gets written to disc is `dave.tar` and is of type `POSIX tar archive`

The file that I send to them is of type `gzip compressed data, was "dave.tar", from Unix, last modified: Fri Aug 28 08:50:50 2015`

Comment: Have you tried changing your response MIME type to something like  `application/binary` ?

Comment: @dotvav - just tried that - no change in behaviour :(